# CSS ::after (and ::before) not working as expected

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I am having problems with CSS pseudo selectors `::after` and `::before`.

```css
.moneygold {
    padding-right: 15px;
}

.moneygold:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    background: url(https://i.ibb.co/QDtRsY4/money-gold.gif) no-repeat;
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;
    float: left;
    margin: 6px 0 0 1px;
}

.moneysilver {
    padding-right: 15px;
}

.moneysilver:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    background: url(https://i.ibb.co/mRDQpvD/money-silver.gif) no-repeat;
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;
    float: left;
    margin: 6px 0 0 1px;
}

.moneycopper {
    padding-right: 15px;
}

.moneycopper:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    background: url(https://i.ibb.co/KGSzwYh/money-copper.gif) no-repeat;
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;
    float: left;
    margin: 6px 0 0 1px;
}
```

```html
<span class="moneygold">3</span>
<span class="moneysilver">17</span>
<span class="moneycopper">20</span>
```

I want the icons to show after each of the corresponding spans, but for some reason they all show **before** the **first** span . I have also observed the same behavior with using `::before` instead of `::after` .

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `display:inline-block` to span

Comment: And remove the float

Comment: PS @TemaniAfif the answer you've posted to, isn't a duplicate. This question doesn't need floats, and should require a new answer.

Comment: @Lee he's using float and the duplicate explain the issue of using float inside inline element and gives a solution thus it's a duplicate ... we need float or not is a different story and opinion based

Comment: IT might be opinion based, but what you've just done is essentially stopped me from providing a valid answer to this question which is DIFFERENT than the one you've linked...

Comment: I've tried to add `display:inline-block` and removed the float and now it shows under the span instead of right...

Comment: don't remove float, simply add `inline-block` to span element

Comment: @TemaniAfif thx, I've returned the float, changed left to right and now it works as intended (forgot I was trying to make a ::before version first).